# how to share content in facebook with users score

Tags: javascript, php, facebook

how to make user share his score on facebook..the user should be able to see his score only after sharing.The user should be able to share with a click then it should reveal his score.

I have attached my html code where the user get scored when he clicks the right answer ,how can i share it in facebbok.

```
<body>

     <li id="q" style="font-size:16px;">A man is very hungry. His stomach is absolutely empty. He have infinite chocolates with him.The man will be killed after 10 minutes.He started eating the chocolates one by one hurriedly. How many chocolates can that 80 kg weighed man eat in his absolutely empty stomach?(your answer should not be in decimal or fraction) </li>
     <ul style="margin-left">
      <li>a). <input  name="q1" type="radio" value="1">10</input></li>
      <li>b). <input  name="q1" type="radio" value="2">0</input></li>
      <li>c). <input  name="q1" type="radio" value="3">Vary from person to person</input><li>
      <li>d). <input  name="q1" type="radio" value="4">1</input></li>
      <li>e). <input  name="q1" type="radio" value="5">48</input></li>
     </ul>                    
     <p id="ans1" style="margin-left:20%; color:red;"></p> 
        <li id="q" style="font-size:16px;"> In what year did Christmas and New Year's fall in the same year?  </li>
          <ul style="margin-left">
          <li>a). <input name="q2" type="radio" value="1">Impossible</input></li>
          <li>b). <input name="q2" type="radio" value="2">1979</input></li>
          <li>c). <input name="q2" type="radio" value="3">Before BC</input><li>
          <li>d). <input name="q2" type="radio" value="4">Every year</input></li>
          <li>e). <input name="q2" type="radio" value="5">None of these</input></li>
          </ul> 
          <p id="ans2" style="margin-left:20%; color:red;"></p>

              <li id="q" style="font-size:16px;">How could you rearrange the letters in the words "new door" to make one word? Note: There is only one correct answer. </li>
                    <br><input type="text" id="q3">
                    <p id="ans2" style="margin-left:20%; color:red;"></p>

              <li  id="q" style="font-size:16px;">If 1/2 of 5x is 3, then what is 1/3 of 10x?  </li>
                <ul style="margin-left">
                    <li>a). <input name="q4" type="radio" value="1">3</input></li>
                    <li>b). <input name="q4" type="radio" value="2">4</input></li>
                    <li>c). <input name="q4" type="radio" value="3">5</input></li>
                </ul> 

               <li id="q" >What number do you get when you multiply all of the numbers on a telephone's number pad?</li>
                <ul>
                    <li>a). <input name="q5" type="radio" value="1">46758,890</input></li>
                    <li>b). <input name="q5" type="radio" value="2">340,000</input></li>
                    <li>c). <input name="q5" type="radio" value="3">0</input></li>
                    <li>d). <input name="q5" type="radio" value="4">None of these</input></li>
                </ul>
               <li id="q">John has been hired to paint the numbers 1 through 100 on 100 apartments. How many times will he have to paint 8?</li>
               <ul>
                   <li>a). <input name="q6" type="radio" value="1">20</input><li>
                   <li>b). <input name="q6" type="radio" value="2">18</input><li>
                   <li>c). <input name="q6" type="radio" value="3">19</input><li>    
               </ul>

               <li id="q">What is the difference between a dollar and a half and thirty five-cents?</li>
                <ul> <li>a). <input name="q7" type="radio" value="1">1 dollar 15 cents</input></li>
                     <li>b). <input name="q7" type="radio" value="2">15 cents</input></li>
                     <li>c). <input name="q7" type="radio" value="3">85 cents></input></li>
                </ul> 

               <li id="q">3,54,204,461,833,1328,1954,?</li>
               <ul>
                   <li>a). <input name="q8" type="radio" value="1">2808</input></li>
                   <li>b). <input name="q8" type="radio" value="2">2708</input></li>
                   <li>c). <input name="q8" type="radio" value="3">2789</input></li>
                   <li>d). <input name="q8" type="radio" value="4">2719</input></li>
                   <li>e). <input name="q8" type="radio" value="5">2706</input></li>
               </ul>

               <li id="q">If all Bloops are Razzies and all Razzies are Lazzies, then are all Bloops definitely Lazzies?</li>
               <ul>
                <li>a). <input name="q9" type="radio" value="1">yes</input></li>
                <li>b). <input name="q9" type="radio" value="2">no</input></li>
                <li>c). <input name="q9" type="radio" value="3">None of these</input></li>
                </ul>

               <li id="q">Mary, who is sixteen years old, is four times as old as her brother. How old will Mary be when she is twice as old as her brother?</li>
               <ul>
                <li>a). <input name="q10" type="radio" value="1">8</input></li>
                <li>b). <input name="q10" type="radio" value="2">25</input></li>
                <li>c). <input name="q10" type="radio" value="3">12</input></li>
                <li>d). <input name="q10" type="radio" value="4">24</input></li>
                <li>e). <input name="q10" type="radio" value="5">26</input></li>
                </ul>                   
    </ol>  
                <input type="submit" name="submit" value="submit"/>

    <button onclick="return score()">Show answers</button>    
    <script type="text/javascript">
 function answer()
 {
     document.getElementById('ans1').innerHTML="1 , he can eat only one with absolutely empty stomache";
     document.getElementById('ans2').innerHTML="Every year, new year in the start and christmas at the end of an year";
 }

 function score()
 {
     var score=0;
     var q1=$("input[type='radio'][name='q1']:checked").val(); 
     var q2=$("input[type='radio'][name='q2']:checked").val();
     var q3=$('#q3').val();
     var q4=$("input[type='radio'][name='q4']:checked").val();
     var q5=$("input[type='radio'][name='q5']:checked").val(); 
     var q6=$("input[type='radio'][name='q6']:checked").val();
     var q7=$("input[type='radio'][name='q7']:checked").val();
     var q8=$("input[type='radio'][name='q8']:checked").val();
     var q9=$("input[type='radio'][name='q9']:checked").val();
     var q10=$("input[type='radio'][name='q10']:checked").val();

     if(q1==4)
     {
         score++;

     };
     if(q2==4)
     {
         score++;

     };
     if(q3=='one word')
     {
         score++;

     };
     if(q4==2)
     {
         score++;

     };
     if(q5==3)
     {
         score++;

     };

     if(q6==1)
     {
         score++;

     };

     if(q7==1)
     {
         score++;

     };

     if(q8==4)
     {
         score++;

     };
     if(q9==1)
     {
         score++;

     };
     if(q10==4)
     {
         score++;

     };

     alert("score is "+score);
 }
```

```
<style type="text/css">
    #q{

        margin-top: 2%;
      }
     ul,input[type="text"]
     {
         margin-left: 10%;
     }
     input[type="text"]
     {
         width:30%;
         background:#ebe4c2;
         color: #000;
     }

</style>  

</body>
```

Comment: _“the user should be able to see his score only after sharing”_ – you are not allowed to force them to share anything. Before you proceed, please go read [Platform Policy](https://developers.facebook.com/policy) (4.5 is the one applying immediately to what you want to do here.)

Comment: if the user want to view the score he can share,if not he can skip.

Comment: it depends on his wish, i have gone through many of such sites which need us to share in order to display the result. Its not forcing i think

Comment: You are not allowed to treat users differently _at all_ depending on whether they share or not. You saying “you only get to see your score if you share” _is_ incentivizing - motivating the user to do something they would not have done otherwise. // And _“other sites are doing it as well”_ is of course not a valid argument at all - people also rob banks, which does not make it legal.